# Categories with comments and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I dont understand how to create this is relationships and routes.
I want to create comments for Category, and for Posts, It's must creating in Category#index and post#index pages.

Here is my code

## category.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: :posts
```

## comment.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :post
```

## post.rb

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :comments, through: :category
```

My migration looks like

## create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  create_table :posts do |t|
   t.integer :category_id
   t.string :name
   t.string :content
   t.string :file

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

And i dont understand how to create routes... for showing comments on post and on categories...

Here is my route

## route.rb

```
resources :categories do 
resources :posts
```

How to create a good relationships, good routes? I dont understand... how to create this model to model relationships and what the fields i must create in migrations...

Comment: Is it like you want a direct association for `post` and `category` with comments, i.e, you want to call something like `@post.comments` and `@category.comments`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it so that a comment can be created either for a post or for a category? In which case, it sounds like a job for a polymorphic association (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Your associations would look something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

This way a post and category can both have many comments, and a comment itself is associated with only one of them (the database columns for commentable therefore has to store not only a reference id, `commentable_id`, but the type of model it's referencing, `commentable_type` - the docs link above has more on the data migration side).

If posts are associated with categories (a category having many posts, and a post having many categories), and you want to instead show comments for a category based on the posts within a category, then your code instead would look a little like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end
```

For this, you'll also need the database migration for a table called `:categories_posts` which will map posts and categories together, without the need for a model between the two. More on that at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to your query you need to add category_id and post_id in comments table. The right way to do this by adding **polymorphic** association to the comments table. Go-rails posted similar tutorial on [rails comments with polymorphic association](https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations?autoplay=1)